# const T * search ( const T &) return not working

Tags: c++, types, reference, return, constants

i have this problem, my program crashes after i started using this function. I don't know how to correctly return required type. Its a binary search in template. I tried changing it to T * search, cast `array[middle]` to const and doing things like `const T * out = &array[middle];` but whenever i add the &, it crashes. If i take it away and return only array[middle], it says:

```
cannot convert 'Fractions' to 'const Fractions*' in return
```

How should i return it correctly?
i have array declared like this and this function is in the same class: It should work with any type, we were given class Fractions to test it, so its normal array of type Fractions, nothing fancy.

```
   T * array;
```

and

```
   const T *search(const T &inElement){


    unsigned low = 0;
    unsigned high = numberOfElements-1;
    unsigned middle = 0;

    while(low <= high){

        middle = low + (high - low)/2;
        if( inElement == array[middle]){
            const T * out = &array[middle]; //problem here
            return out;

        }
        else if(inElement < array[middle]){
          high = middle -1;
        }
        else{
           low = middle + 1;
        }


    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Pointers and references were always problem for me, i read similar topics bout this with vectors and still cant understand it.

The rest of my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fractions.cpp"

using namespace std;




template<class T,unsigned n>

class SortedArray {

T * array;
unsigned length;
unsigned numberOfElements;
T element;
unsigned position;


public:

SortedArray() {
    length = n;
    array = new T[n];
    numberOfElements = 0;
    position = 0;
}



bool first(){

    if(numberOfElements >= 1){
        element = array[0];
        position = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool next(){

 if(position+1 < numberofElements){
  position++;
  element = array[position];
  return true;
 }
 return false;

}

const T & aktual(){
 return element;
}


SortedArray & operator << (const T &element){


    if(numberOfElements == length || search(element) == NULL){return (*this);}
    if(numberOfElements == length){return (*this);}

    int i = numberOfElements;
    for (; i > 0 && array[i-1] > element; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }

    array[i] = element;
    numberOfElements++;
    return (*this);
}



operator unsigned () const{
return numberOfElements;
}



const T *search(const T &inElement){
//this is the function causing problems

}




~SortedArray() {
    delete [] array;
    array = NULL;
}




};



int main()
{

    SortedArray<Fractions,20> pz;

    typedef Fractions Z;

    pz << Z(1,3) << Z(3,5) << Z(7,4) << Z(3,4) << Z(2,3) << Z(7,2)

     << Z(5,4) << Z(1,4) << Z(6,7) << Z(4,3) << Z(2,3);


    cout << "\nNumber of elements : " << pz.operator unsigned() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not enough code context to tell!

Comment: What is the type of `array`?

Comment: Where's `array` coming from? Could you post some of the code where it's called as well please?

Comment: In the error message there is name X. However in your code snippet there is no such name.

Comment: Have you can tried returning the index value instead of the pointer?

Comment: Ok, i added the rest of my class, and no, i cant return the index value, it must be pointer to this element.

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean? Exact description of failure mode required. And what has your debugging revealed?

Comment: There is no need for the variable "length" when you have n as a template parameter.

Comment: @Mike: ... and no need for dynamic allocation as well.

Comment: @user3104644: Why is the `numberOfElements == length` comparison done twice at the beginning of `operator <<`?

Comment: @AndreyT that is correct as well

Answer (score 2):

Your function fails when `numberOfElements` is 0. You have the line:

```
unsigned high = numberOfElements-1;
```

When `numberOfElements` is 0, `high` will receive the value `-1` casted to `unsigned int`, which is a very large number. This will cause access to the array beyond its end, which is undefined behavior and often will crash.

As for your question about the `return` statement, what you have now is correct.